# Read XML file using perl

Tags: xml, perl

I have an XML file which looks like this, I wish to retrieve the value of RAM. Im pretty new to perl. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<hardware>
 <computer OS="Linux" ENV="DEV">2GB</computer>
 <computer OS="windows" ENV="QA">3GB</computer>
</hardware>
```

Its more like a query to retrieve a value.eg: "perl myscript.pl Linux DEV" should give me "2GB" as the output.

Comment: Use an XML-parsing library like [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML) or [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig)

Comment: ...or [`XML::Rabbit`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Rabbit) (I've used it and really liked it), or [one of the modules listed in `Task::Kensho`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Task::Kensho#Task::Kensho::XML:-XML-Development) or [some other module](https://metacpan.org/search?q=xml).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

f you only need to get the values inside the XML tag, use a simple regexp match:

```
foreach (split(/\n/,$xmltext))
{
    print "$1\n" if /<computer.*>(.*)<\/computer>/;
}
```

If you want to process the whole XML structure (as you should do), use an XML module like XML::Parser

MOD:

For query-like search, you have to use an XML parser, for example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Bare;

my $parser = new XML::Bare( file => "ram.xml" );
print $_->{value}."\n" foreach (@{$parser->find_by_perl($parser->parse()->{hardware}->{computer}, "(-OS eq '$ARGV[0]') && (-ENV eq '$ARGV[1]')")});
```

This will list ALL values matching your criteria

Comment: Its more like a query to retrieve a value.eg: "perl myscript.pl Linux DEV" should give me "2GB" as the output.

Comment: How can i give xml file as an input to search instead of
my $xml = <<END
<hardware>
<computer OS="Linux" ENV="DEV">2GB</computer>
<computer OS="windows" ENV="QA">3GB</computer>
</hardware>
END
;

Comment: my $parser = new XML::Bare( file => "ram.xml" );

Comment: I modified the code above, and added command line parameters (no checking though, so you MUST call it with two parameters for OS and ENV).
If you find this answer satisfactory, please accept it (by clicking on the tick on the top left of this answer)

Comment: You are the best! It works like a charm!!

I will update few error handling and command line parameter checks from here on!!
You saved my day!

Comment: Can i make it case insensitive search?

Comment: "(-OS =~ /^$ARGV[0]\$/i) && (-ENV =~ /^$ARGV[1]\$/i)"

Answer (score 1):

Using [`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/XML-LibXML/LibXML.pod):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

use XML::LibXML;

die "Usage: $0 <OS> <ENV>\n" if @ARGV != 2;

my ($os, $env) = @ARGV;

my $xml = XML::LibXML->load_xml(IO => \*DATA);

say $xml->findvalue(qq{//computer[\@OS = "$os"][\@ENV = "$env"]})

__DATA__
<hardware>
 <computer OS="Linux" ENV="DEV">2GB</computer>
 <computer OS="windows" ENV="QA">3GB</computer>
</hardware>
```

Or using [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);

use XML::Twig;

die "Usage: $0 <OS> <ENV>\n" if @ARGV != 2;

my ($os, $env) = @ARGV;

my $t = XML::Twig->new( 
    twig_handlers => {
        qq{//computer[\@OS="$os" and \@ENV="$env"]} => sub { say $_->text() },
    },
);
$t->parse( do {local $/; <DATA>} );

__DATA__
<hardware>
 <computer OS="Linux" ENV="DEV">2GB</computer>
 <computer OS="windows" ENV="QA">3GB</computer>
</hardware>
```

Outputs:

```
$ perl script.pl Linux DEV
2GB
```